# Prevent plug-in scripts on a specific template?

Tags: plugins, templates, hooks

I have a plug-in which is interfering with my Google Map Embed in the template I'm using for my about page.

Is there a way to prevent that plug-in from hooking in all of it's script files through wp_footer just on that particular template. It adds like 4 js files which aren't necessary for that page/template.

Comment: Yes its possible, what is the plug-in that is causing the issue?

Comment: [myEventOn](http://www.myeventon.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `myEventOn` is a propitiatory plugin its difficult to provide a specific solution. However since your only have an issue on one page your best bet might be to use the [Plugin Organizer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/) plugin, which allows you to disable plugins by post type or by URL.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this suggestion and I will investigate Plugin Organizer. If you would like to provide a more general solution for non-proprietary plugins I would be happy to give you the answer. It's something I'd like to know how to do in the general case. Cheers!